# What happens if Sync Adapter fails first time sync? Does it wait for whole period to try syncing again?

Tags: android

For example if first time there is no network connection,does it wait for whole period (pollfrequency time, addPeriodicSync) again to try syncing again (REST with local database)?

Comment: depends on SyncResults ... and android version :) ...  but IMHO(I don't remeber when i did analyze that part of android framework but i did), no(in every android version) if you mark it as ioexception in syncresult then it will try: with some backoff or after device "go online" ... answers are in android.content.SyncManager class ...

Comment: @Selvin Thanks, so that is the solution, adding exception in syncresult so it reinitiates sync.

Comment: you didn't it already? in onPerformSync I used to use `catch (IOException ex) { syncResult.stats.numIoExceptions++; }` in such cases